# How to set up log appender - kaa project

Tags: mongodb, kaa

I'm trying "Your-first-Kaa-application", but i have a stuck at "Set up log appender" step.

http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/MongoDB-log-appender/

Flow the example at the link above, they set mongoServers with "host" and "port" like below text:

```
"mongoServers":[
    {
        "host":"127.0.0.1",
        "port":27017
    }
```

But I don't understand `host` and `port` mean, and in my situation (My own network, my own computer, my own kaa sandbox server ...)

How to find my system's `host`and `port`.

Please help me!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The MongoDB log appender is responsible for transferring logs from the
>   Operations service to the MongoDB database.

So that means you should install [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/) and run it.And then add your MongoDB server `host` and `port` to the configuration.

Comment: Thank McGrady for your answer,

I have a little confusing,
my kaa sandbox server address is: 10.49.46.36:9080
so, my MongoDB host is 10.49.46.36, port is 9080 ?

I am not sure all of them are one, could you confirm to me? McGrady,

Thank you!

Comment: @TrầnQuốcViệt. I think you should check out your server,and make sure there is a MongoDB server running.If not,you should install MongoDB and specific a port(default 27017 port) to run it. If they're running on the same server,`kaa` can use `127.0.0.1`  as `host` and `27017` as `port` to connect MongoDB.

Comment: Yep, bro :) :) :)